# creating function using matlab

Tags: matlab

I wrote the following function

```
% e is n×1 and y is n×1 vectors
function z=e_rand(e,y)
         b_LS=regress(e,y)
         z=b_LS*5
```

I saved the function in MATLAB toolbox. 
But when I **run** the function I get the following error:
input argument "e" is undefined

How can I create the function correctly?

Answer (score 6):

You DON'T RUN a function. You use it in an expression. You call your function at the command line. But you don't use the run command on a function. Run is only for scripts, not functions.

At the command line, just type this:

```
z = e_rand(e,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave your function as-is, and encapsulate your function within another function, then you need to give e and y values in a parent function.

Try this:

```
    function parent()
    clear all, close all
    n = randi(10, 1)
    e = rand(n, 1)
    y = rand(n, 1)
    z = e_rand(e, y)

        % e is [n×1] and y is [n×1] vectors
        function z = e_rand(e, y)
                 b_LS = regress(e, y)
                 z = b_LS * 5
        end
    end
```

Works cited: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html